# Simplify conditional statements in Python

Tags: python

Can this be further simplified?

```
def __init__(a: int, b: int):
    if not a and not b:
       raise
    
    if a and b:
       raise
    
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
```

I am trying to check the following

1. If a is provided then b should not be given
2. If b is provided then a should not be given
3. One of them is mandatory

Any recommendations on simplifying such conditional statements?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to check with the if conditions. two `if` statements completely contradicting each other

Comment: I think you meant `def __init__(a: int, b: int):` ?

Comment: @deadshot - I think it's checking for exclusively a or b only

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to express that the *boolean value of both arguments needs to be different:*

```
if bool(a) == bool(b):
    raise
```